# how to route local IP to use NIC and other to use Wifi NIC

Tags: networking, router, network-adapter

Like most, my desktop has Wifi NIC and LAN NIC
but today most of the time we only use Wifi ... since most house does not have LAN in every room

but I want to create a specific network that does not connect to the other

here is what I have in my mind

INTERNET -- ROUTER1 --(*via wifi*)-- DESKTOP  --(*via wired LAN*)-- ROUTER2 -- OLD COMPUTER

So I want to be able to grab files from my old computer
but my old computer will not see anything other than a ROUTER2

how to configure my desktop and router2

Router1 is in 192.168.0 network
so my wifi nic card has 192.168.0.x IP address

and I would like My wired lan to be on 10.0.0.10 ip address
and I can set My router2 to be in 10.0.0 range

my old computer IP address will be 10.0.0.11
So if I type \\10.0.0.11 on my desktop , I can see shared files of my old computer

any pointer? is it a simple host file and gateway setting that will allow me to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy, just don't set a default gateway in the TCP settings for the wired network card, and the OS will take care of the rest.

By doing the setup this way it will use your wired network card for all 10.x.x.x requests then use the wireless card for everything else outside of that range (all 192.168.0.x requests and any requests for IP's on the internet).